# How do I automatically reload my agenda views on window/frame resize?

Tags: org-agenda, window, frames

I've noticed that my agenda views get squashed (line breaks) when my window/frame resizes, e.g. when I move the Emacs frame to a smaller monitor. Is there a way/hook to automatically reload my open agendas (I usually have a daily view and a custom agenda command open sticky) in the background when the frame resizes? I couldn't quite find the right thing in the help menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect a size change when you move the frame from one monitor to another by using `window-size-change-functions` (see its doc string with `C-h v window-size-change-functions`). Here's a simple example that prints a message out when that happens:

```el
(defun wscf (obj)
  (message (format "%S: size change" obj)))

(add-to-list 'window-size-change-functions #'wscf)
```

We define a function and then add it to the list. When the size changes, the functions in the list (in this case just `wscf`) are called. This function produces a message that looks something like this:

```
#<frame emacs@some.hostname.org: *Messages* 0x19c11b0>: size change
```

Now all you have to do is modify the function to do what you want, for example:

```
(defun wscf (obj)
  (org-agenda-redo 'all))
```

Now when the size changes, the new function is called which redoes the agenda. The argument to `org-agenda-redo` causes it to rebuild *all* agenda views (it can be anything non-nil, so `t` would work just as well).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! For other users interested: It does make it a bit stutter-y when you drag-resize a window, but is perfect for my use case (maximising, tiling window manager etc.).